# Unrecognized unicode result from AES decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I try to build simple AES encryption helper to encrypt/decrypt some strings
Fist, I have an issue with Padding mode wherein decryption it only accepts if Zero otherwise an error about padding occurs!
The second issue is when I try to encrypt simple string "Hello World," it got encrypted, and I have the base64 string, but when trying to decrypt, there's no error, but a weird unknown character is shown! like 㡲啁䎰廾ử靱힩㡲啁䎰廾ử靱힩
My code:

```
        private static int keySizes = 256;
        private static int blockSize = 128;
        private static PaddingMode pMode = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        private static CipherMode cMode = CipherMode.ECB;
        private static byte[] key = GenEncryptionKey();
        private const string passphrase = @"StartYourMorningWithASmile";

    private static byte[] GenEncryptionKey()
    {
        HashAlgorithm hash = MD5.Create();
        return hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(passphrase));
    }

    private static AesManaged CreateCryptor()
    {
        AesManaged cryptor = new AesManaged();
        cryptor.KeySize = keySizes;
        cryptor.BlockSize = blockSize;
        cryptor.Padding = pMode;
        cryptor.Key = key;
        cryptor.Mode = cMode;
        cryptor.GenerateIV();
        return cryptor;
    }
public static string EncryptParams(string reqVal)
        {
            string cipherText = "";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reqVal) || reqVal.Length < 1)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(reqVal);

            using (var cryptor = CreateCryptor())
            {
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = cryptor.CreateEncryptor();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

                    }
                    byte[] cipherBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
                }
                cryptor.Clear();
            }
            return cipherText;

        }



        public static string DecryptParams(string resVal)
        {
            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(resVal);
            byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[data.Length];
            string plainText = "";

            using (var crypto = CreateCryptor())
            {


                ICryptoTransform Dec = crypto.CreateDecryptor();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Dec, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                crypto.Clear();
            }

            return plainText;
        }
```

Comment: Fast +1 for providing a reproducible example

Comment: ECB mode is not secure because it isn't randomized, and your code will fail again if you use CBC because you generate a new IV for encryption & decryption.

Comment: Can you please mark as answer? Means a lot to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE 1:

Please set also the IV yourself to achieve successful decryption, as @maarten-bodewes pointed out. I missed that part and the decryption somehow worked (?) with your existing code, but you always should provide the same key and IV to a symmetric encryption algorithm to have it work both ways.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Your decryption fails (produces incorrect results) because you implemented the decryption part incorrectly (by using `CryptoStreamMode.Write` instead of `CryptoStreamMode.Read`) and besides feeding the decryption stream all zero bytes

At the point of execution of

```
cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
```

the variable `cipherBytes` is all zero. The real encrypted buffer is in the `data` variable which you only use to set the length of `cipherBytes`

So change your decryption method to this.

**BONUS**: After correcting the decryption part, you can specify the padding as you wish! I tested with PKCS7 and it is ok.

```
public static string DecryptParams(string resVal)
{
    var cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(resVal);
    string plainText = "";

    using (var crypto = CreateCryptor())
    {
        ICryptoTransform Dec = crypto.CreateDecryptor();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Dec, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] decryptBlock = new byte[4096];
                MemoryStream decryptStream = new MemoryStream();
                int readBytes;
                while ((readBytes = cs.Read(decryptBlock, 0, 4096)) > 0)
                {
                    decryptStream.Write(decryptBlock, 0, readBytes);
                }
                plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        crypto.Clear();
    }

    return plainText;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Oguz you give some good point on my code, I changed it, and it works grate

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oguz

Below is my description method after edit

```
public static string DecryptParams(string resVal)
        {
            var data = Convert.FromBase64String(resVal);
            byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[data.Length];
            string plainText = "";

            using (var crypto = CreateCryptor())
            {  
                ICryptoTransform Dec = crypto.CreateDecryptor();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, Dec, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        cs.Read(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(cipherBytes.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                crypto.Clear();
            }

            return plainText;
        }
```

one more thing about the return result after the decryption I got the original string plus \0\0\0\0 so I use myString.TrimEnd('\0') to solve that.